# Multiple JFrames in a single application

Tags: java

I have two JFrames in my java code, when I close one frame second frame is closed automatically, please tell how I can make them independent of each other?

My code is like this:

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();

frame1.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame1.setUndecorated(true);
frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame1.setVisible(true);

frame2.setSize(200,100);
frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame2.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Hi, can you show what you have attempted, in terms of research and your relevant code. Be sure to include any errors or unexpected ouptuts in the code. This doesn't show even minimal effort made first.

Comment: It's not that closing the first frame closes the second frame, it's that closing the first frame exits the program entirely.

Comment: Yep sorry taggedt he wrong one. Still though where is the research, the code, the stack trace and / or outputs? If one is closed, then close the other... in Java.

Comment: You probably want to look at [setDefaultCloseOperation(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

It is not that easy to answer, when no code snippet is attached.

But i assume, that you have called

```
JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

> EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the
>   System exit method. Use this only in applications.

In this case you have to change it to

```
WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
```

Comment: I have added a portion of my code in my post. now please help if anyone can.